# How to show expected parameters for a function in IntelliJ IDEA community?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am a beginner in Java and just installed IntelliJ IDEA Community because my programming course is working with that IDE.

Now e.g. when I write something like

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDate = new SimpleDateFormat(
```

I would expect that IntelliJ IDEA shows what parameters (type) is needed but it won't show what parameters I have to enter.

Is there a quick way of setting that up? When I learned C# in Visual Studio a little popup always showed me what parameters are expected for each possible method.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a mac or windows?

Comment: I am using Windows.

Comment: That's Ctrl+P. IntelliJ has loads of shortcuts for these things, in time you will see it is even better than Visual Studio. Something else, don't use `SimpleDateFormat`. That's old and buggy! Use the new `DateTimeFormatter` from Java 8's Time API.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you may use Ctrl+P to see the parameters, but Ctrl+Q gives you more information about the function.

Comment: There's no matter ;)